# Как создать службу для Windows

Tags: windows, delphi

Как создать службу для `Windows 7` или `XP` в `Delphi 7`. Если возможно, приведите, пожалуйста, пошаговую инструкцию, как можно подробней.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно для программы сделать автоматический запуск на уровне службы windows?

Comment: а дельфи принципиален? на C# это реализуется парой кликов

Answer (score 2):

На английском:

- [Tutorial for making a Service Application using Delphi](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/service/service.htm#Create a service)
- [Building applications, components, and libraries](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/service/buildap.htm)

На русском:

- [Пример службы на Delphi (WinAPI)](http://www.kb.mista.ru/article.php?id=580)

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже сейчас со службой сижу, почитайте [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/71533/) =)

Answer (score 0):

В интернете полно статей на эту тему, как пример серия статей [1](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-windows-service-applications.htm), [2](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Creating-a-Windows-Service-in-Delphi/). Напишите что конкретно не получается. А так, кроме ссылок Вам ничего не ответят.

Answer (score 0):

вот тебе пошаговая инструкция

Допустим твой файл называется testService.exe

1. Копируешь свой файл в Windows/System32, если у тебя 64 битная винда он автоматически скопируется и в Windows/SysWow64
2. Запускаешь командную строку под админом и в ней пишешь

если windows 32 bit:

```
sc create "AAA" binpath= C:\WINDOWS\system32\TestService.exe type= own start= auto displayname= "AAA" error= ignore
```

если Windows 64 bit:

```
sc create "AAA" binpath= C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\TestService.exe type= own start= auto displayname= "AAA" error= ignore
```

3. Reboot и все твоя служба установлена и работает